# Replace multiple characters in As3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I faced difficulties to replace a string.

```
var expression:String = '2X3';
var inString:String = expression;
inString=inString.replace("÷","/");
inString=inString.replace("X","*");
trace('Result.....',inString);
```

Output:-
Result.....2*3

Its alright.
But the problem was when i tried to give input as

> var expression:String = '2X3X3X4X5X6';

output:-

> Result.....2*3X3X4X5X6

But i need it in form of

> Result.....2*3*3*4*5*6

and same for division.
Thanks & Regards

Comment: myString = myString.replace(/X/g, "*"); Good luck ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this for replacing all

```
var result:String=inString.split("X").join("*");
```

Comment: @subrat71 np, don't forget to vote up good responses and the best one mark it as the right answer

Answer (score 2):

I know you've already selected a answer, but it lacked an explanation and a proper solution. The reason you see this happening is that `String.replace()`, when the `pattern` is a `String`, only replaces the first result. The solution is to use `RegEx`:

```
var expression:String = '2x3X3x4X5X6';
var result:String = expression.replace(/x/ig, "*");
trace(result); // output 2*3*3*4*5*6
```

The pattern uses two flags, global and case-insensitivity. That will grab all instances of the letter X, regardless of case, and search the entire string. The benefit with `RegEx` is that is extremely low level. There is little-to-no overhead when using a regular expression meaning they are incredibly fast. `String.split` and `String.join` use loops to function, I believe, which are considerably slower. Additionally, you have to store an additional array in memory.

Granted, these are negligible in most cases (difference in the 10's of microseconds, maybe), but not all. I had a project the required files to be scrambled. Unfortunately, the files were too large (200MB minimum) and the doing the `replace().join()` method was 4-5 slower than the `RegEx` method. With `RegEx`, I managed to reduce the lag while scrambling from a few seconds to 2-3 frames.

Comment: i understand what you are saying...and thanks for that .....But i needed one solution for it and from them i choose one...

Comment: I understand. SO is more than just a QA site. It's an archive. A wiki. A globally accepted center for programming information. It is not uncommon for answers to be added after-the-fact in order to add to that database of information. That is all I wanted to do here.

Comment: this answer is better i think

Answer (score -1):

did you try `inString=inString.replaceAll("X","*");`? notice the "All" suffix!

Comment: yeah i tried that one but there was no method as ReplaceAll().